# ionic does not reflect the changes done in src folder

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I have an open source project : https://github.com/moodlehq/moodleapp
I have downloaded it and change images in asset and it reflect, but when I change in the lang files or colors it does not

I tried `ionic build` and `ionic serve` many times, but still does not work

Comment: With the browser or a device ?

Comment: browser, I did not try on devices yet

Comment: Are you referring to your app icons and splash screen, or are these regular in-app assets (like you'd use in web)?